# DataContractSerializer tracing performance when read object

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer

During the profiling session we noticed that `DataContractSerializer.ReadObject` spend 25-30% of time on tracing. What we see in the profiler is that `ReadObject` creates `DiagnosticUtility` and do some stuff with reading config sections. All that `DiagnosticUtility` code takes 321 milliseconds when actual object reading takes 838 milliseconds.

Our `app.config` is empty, so there is no listeners, but we see that `DiagnosticUtility` adds a default listener. Unfortunately, we don't have access to the `DiagnosticUtility`.

Is there any way to disable unnecessary diagnostic tracing?

Comment: You're probably running in debug mode.  Run release, or remove the trace  constant definition from the build and the issue probably goes away.

Comment: @Will, thank you very much. TRACE was set. Unchecking that option changes nothing. We still see those odd traces of DiagnosticUtility.

Comment: Running in release mode?

Comment: Yes, running in release mode.

Comment: That seems very odd.  At this point, I'd buss out the reference http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/DataContractSerializer.cs go through it and see what and where this is happening, and how to turn it off.  Someone might answer, but...